# Zip large number of files into n zipfiles

Tags: bash, zip

I have a large number of files in a folder. How can I zip all files so that I have n files per zipfile.

I know you can split by size with `--split-size` but it requires the file size of the final zips. I want to specify the number of files that will be contained in a single zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will take all files from the current directory and save them, `n` at time (where n=10 in this example), into zip archives:

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 bash -c 'zip $$.zip "$@"' none
```